# Is it possible to load jinja2 templates without having variables replaced?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Suppose we have the following structure

**templates/modal.html**

```
<div class="title">
   {% block title %}
   {% endblock %}
</div>
<div class="content">
   {% block content %}
   {% endblock %}
</div>
```

**templates/usermodal.html**

```
{% extends "modal.html" %}
{% block title %}
     Hello {{ user }}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
     Some content
     {% include "table.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

**template/table.html**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         {{ data }}
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to return to the client side the following content, to populate it with js/client side templating

```
<div class="title">
     Hello {{ user }}
</div>
<div class="content">
     Some content
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{ data }}
       </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

So basically what I'm looking for is a method similar to render_template in flask, but which only assembles the template, but doesn't populate/render it with data.

Looking around in the sources, I couldn't find such method.

Do you have any ideas how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Why not just pass in `"{{user}}"` as the value of `user` and `"{{data}}"` as the value of `data`?

Comment: Sure, could work, but that is quite an overhead, maintaining all variables in both places. I thought there might be a more "official" way of doing it - only I just didn't come across it

Comment: in flask you have template preprocessor functions, which can be used to deal with boilerplate-y variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mark block with `raw`

```
{% raw %}
    <div class="title">
         Hello {{ user }}
    </div>
    <div class="content">
         Some content
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              {{ data }}
           </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
{% endraw %}
```

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#escaping

Answer (score 1):

Very late to this question, but I was looking for a solution for this exact problem and couldn't find any.

Originally this answer presented 3 "solutions" for the problem described in the question. But after I played with them some more I've realised that there is something I missed about what we're actually trying to achieve:

According to the original question, we only want to render `{% block %}` and `{% include %}` (and maybe `{% macro %}`) expressions. We can't resolve `{% if %}` or `{% for %}` expressions because they require **the value of a variable** (unless we're using a const, but that is a whole other story).

The "solutions" I presented were trying to render the template completely, including if/for/set/call expressions (and Jinja2 filters), using Jinja2's configurations and internal code. This was not successful because as I mentioned, it makes no sense to resolve `{% if A %}` when we don't know the value of the variable `A`.

This leads me to believe that the **simplest way to solve this is not by using Jinja2**, but by resolving the `include` and `extends` blocks using regex:

1. Find whether this template extends another. If it does, read the original template *(this can be done either with `open(file_path, 'r')` or with Jinja2 `get_source()` function)*.
2. Find all blocks in the original template and replace them in the "parent" template. Repeat steps 1+2 until we reach a template that does not extend another.
3. Find all `{% include %}` tags, read the contents of the included files and insert them into the template.

The result: a template where all `include` and `extends` were resolved... which as I understand, is what we're after.